# Converting a string into equation and resolve it

Tags: python, string, sympy

All i need to do is convert a String into an simple object like:
`"1/4*x+ 1" to 1/4*x+ 1`
I am extracting text from image and calculating the expression in the image.
If i get:
`valid_text = 1/4*x+ 1= 1/6*x+ 1/2` from image, I am doing:

```
if 'x' in valid_text and '=' in valid_text:
    lhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[0]
    lhs = eval(lhs)
    rhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[1]
    rhs = eval(rhs)
    solution = solve(Eq(lhs, rhs), x)
```

I am using `eval()` function to return an object when i pass a String into it. But `eval()` function sometimes gives

```
rhs = eval(rhs)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` **AND other inappropriate outputs.**
```

Is there any other way to get an object from String?

Comment: You will also have to find out the possible data types before applying. In this case you are expecting `int` but to help yourself you could put `int` and `float` all into `float`

Comment: use `literal_eval` from `ast`

Comment: please put a complete code that show the error for `valid_text = 1/4*x+ 1= 1/6*x+ 1/2`

Comment: `In [44]: np.polyval([1./4,1],2)
Out[44]: 1.5
`Use numpy polyval

Comment: question title seems a little ambiguous as `strings` in python are `objects`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete solution

```py
from sympy import solve
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

def solve_meThis(string_):
    try:
        lhs =  parse_expr(string_.split("=")[0])
        rhs =  parse_expr(string_.split("=")[1])
        solution = solve(lhs-rhs)
        return solution
    except:
        print "invalid equation"

valid_text = "1/4*x+ 1 = 1/6*x+ 1/2"
solve_meThis(valid_text)

>> -6
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked like a charm. I also tried the below solution and it worked: `if 'x' in valid_text and '=' in valid_text:
            t = locate('sympy.sympify')
            lhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[0]
            lhs = t(lhs)
            rhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[1]
            rhs = t(rhs)

            solution = solve(Eq(lhs, rhs), x)`

Comment: @farhava I did it my way at the end but i also tried your way that worked for me.Actually your solution `solution = solve(lhs-rhs)` is only for particular type of equation. I am working on all kind of algebric equations. So i used `solution = solve(Eq(lhs, rhs), x)` from `sympy` library.

Comment: than accept yours =) the idea is to accept an answer to make your question more helpful

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do symbolic calculus. python is not handling, as far as I know, this type of problem but the library simpy seems to do so. you can find information about it at http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/sympy.html

Another approach would be to develop a grammar and syntaxic parser yourself but as already said, it's a long way to go.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the strings you're trying to parse represent SymPy expressions, then [`sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html) looks like the tool for the job.

```
In [8]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

In [9]: parse_expr('2*x*sin(x)')
Out[9]: 2*x*sin(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from sympy import *
from pydoc import locate
x, y, z, p, q, r, m, n, i, j = symbols('x y z p q r m n i j')
    if 'x' in valid_text and '=' in valid_text:
        t = locate('sympy.sympify')
        lhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[0]
        lhs = t(lhs)
        rhs = valid_text.rsplit('=', 1)[1]
        rhs = t(rhs)

        solution = solve(Eq(lhs, rhs), x)
```